# ModelChoiceForm not showing any values

Tags: python, django

I have a this Model `Apuntes` in my `models.py` file:

```
class Apuntes(models.Model):
    PRIVACY_CHOICES=(
        ('public', 'Público'),
        ('private', 'Privado'),
        ('password', 'Protegido')
    )
    owner=models.ForeignKey(User)
    privacy=models.CharField("Privacidad", max_length=10, choices=PRIVACY_CHOICES, default='private')
    password=models.CharField("Contraseña", max_length=20, blank=True)
    asignatura=models.ForeignKey(Asignaturas)
    datos=models.FileField()
    descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have also a Form made from this Model `ApuntesForm` in `forms.py`:

```
class ApuntesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Apuntes
        fields = ['privacy', 'password', 'asignatura', 'datos', 'descripcion']
        widgets = {
            'descripcion': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'privacy': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'asignatura': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

When I try to use this form in a view, the `Asignaturas` Select field doesn't show properly:

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YPUb.png)

I want it to show the `nombre` column in the database, not just a generic object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
class Asignaturas(models.Model):
    ...
    #your fields
    ...
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

;)

Comment: This fixed it. I used `__str__` instead of `__unicode__` as @chet pilley suggested, though. Pity that Django docs are such a maze. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> `__str__`
>
> `Model.__str__()` The `__str__()` method is called whenever you
>   call `str()` on an object. Django uses `str(obj)` in a number of places.
>   **Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the
>   value inserted into a template when it displays an object.** Thus, you
>   should always return a nice, human-readable representation of the
>   model from the `__str__()` method.
>
> For example:

```
from django.db import models 
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible`

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

> If you’d like compatibility with Python 2, you can decorate your model class
>   with [python_2_unicode_compatible()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible) as shown above.

Puam's answer would work in Python 2.7, but if you're in 3 you'll want to read the **str** and **unicode** methods section in Django docs' [Port to Python 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods)